# If $F \subset E$ is Galois and there is a subfield of $E$ thats not normal, describe and find number of subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I know [F:E] = 8 and I need to describe the structure of all subfields and then find all subfields that are normal and not equal to $F$ or $E$.

Since [F:E] = 8, I know that $| \operatorname{Gal} (F/E)| = 8$, but I have no idea where to start so any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, there is a one-to-one correspondence between subfields of $E$ containing $F$ and subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$. Moreover, a subfield $F\subset K\subset E$ is normal if and only if the corresponding subgroup $\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)\leq \mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ is normal.

Now, there is a very short list of groups of order $8$, and only one of them has a subgroup that is not normal.

Comment: So the by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, we know that teh structure of the subfields is just that they are subgroups if the Galois group and they are Galois iff the subgroup is Galois.  Is that enough to say?

Comment: As for b, the groups are $D_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Or wait... the quaternion group,  not $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: Does the group of quaternions have a subgroup that is not normal?

Comment: No.  So is there an easier way to count the number of not normal subgroups of $D_4$ or do I just check each individually?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, but is there a way we can move this conversation to chat?